# How I can transform Photoshop GUI, into Java GUI interface?

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like from an interface design in photoshop. To integrate these elements Design on components java buttons, slider, etc ...

Here's a photoshop interface example, I would like in components java:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: hi, thanks for using the stackoveflow. Unfortunately for you this is Question&Answer site where questions should be concrete. Answer for your question is opinion based and require multiple steps. Please read FAQ and came back with specific problem. Good luck

Comment: Appart from this ... your example image is grabbed from a blog that explains in detail (including example project) how to build such a UI ... so why not just read the blog?

Comment: You are right about the blog. But it's an old project 20120107 with some problems to compile with JDK 1.8. So if I pose this question it's in order to know if some people have new way to make something like this or software, anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how far your design goes. If you simply want to have normal Swing components on top of your image this is easy. Convert your PSD into (for example) PNG, create a custom JPanel subclass that loads the image and overwrite the paintComponent()-method to draw the image instead of the normal background. All child components can then be set to be transparent with setOpaque(false). This puts your image into the background and puts the components float on top of it.

If you want to change how individual components look, its a lot more work. You basically need to implement a new Look&Feel for Swing. I wouldn't recommend going that route, unless you really have to, we are talking about weeks of work here, and it requires a lot of testing to really make it work properly on all platforms.

Alternately, there are already tons of custom Look&Feels available, I suggest you take a look at some freely available ones (just google "java look and feel"). Many of them can be customized to some degree (how much depends on the actual implementation, so take a close look at the source/documentation for each of them).